# Load all image in the contain folder to image slider

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html

So i'm taking over someone else work, i need help on loading all image into the image slider. So i put all image in one folder and i want the image slider to show all the image in that folder one by one. I can make the slider show one image only, when i debug the code the problem is it always get the name of the last image in the folder.

On the Dim str_filename i always get the name of the last image only. Thank You for any helps.

```
Function Setup_Slider_photo(ByVal str_path As String, ByVal str_slider As String) As String
    Dim str_html As String = ""

    If str_path.StartsWith("file:") Then
        str_path = str_path.Remove(0, 5)
    End If
    str_path = str_path.Replace("/", "\")

    If impersonateValidUser("reportingserver", "carsem", "password") Then
        Dim file_all As ArrayList = folder_bll.show_file_list(str_path)

        Dim file_list As New ArrayList
        str_html += "<div class='camera_wrap' id='camera_wrap_1' style='height:450px;'>"
        If file_all.Count > 0 Then

            For index As Integer = 1 To 12
                file_list.Add(file_all(0).ToString.Trim)
                Dim str_file_name As String = file_list.Item(file_list.Count - 1).ToString.Trim.Substring(0, file_list.Item(file_list.Count - 1).ToString.Trim.Length - 4).Trim
                str_html += "<div data-src='" & str_path.Replace("\\carsem.com.my\filesvr\CSSFILE1\", "..\CSSFILE1\") & file_list.Item(file_list.Count - 1).ToString & "'>"
                str_html += "<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6'><a href='../Event/Event_Image.aspx?e=" & str_slider & "' target='_self' style='text-decoration: none; cursor:hand' class='btn btn-sm animated-button victoria-two'>Click To View More</a></div>"
                str_html += "</div>"
            Next



        End If
        str_html += "</div>"

        undoImpersonation()
    End If
    Return str_html
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use your `index` in place of `file_list.Count - 1` inside the loop.